# Can I make a bridge between GSM Arduino shield with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, hardware, arduino

I am trying to do some work with  Raspberry Pi, however, I have GSM Arduino shield laying at home. I want to give a voice-call using it. However, I still wondering how can I interface voice/mic, should I use the input of Arduino or should I get/send voice through speaker/mic of arduino or raspberry-pi.

Anyone has experience in doing work with that?

Comment: Please can you ask a more clear question. I dont understand what you mean with `should I get/send voice through speaker/mic of arduino or raspberry-pi` ?? Typically the GSM Shield has audio in and out. So, what do you want to do with the Audio from the GSM shield?

Comment: @ppumkin I don't have audio in and out in my GSM Shield (can u provide a link, I kept searching to make sure that I am not wrong). And it's easier (and cheaper for me) to get Audio in/out for raspberry pi using usb shield. The Question: Let's say that I am building a phone. I have a GSM Shield connected to arduino, it can dial/makcalls. Now when I make a call I need to hear the caller, and talk to him. I connected it raspberrypi to bridge to raspberrypi speaker/mic. The problem, how can I make that bridge.

Comment: `Which EXACT shield have you got?` Sometimes the audio is not soldered. Sometimes, on really bad shields they just don't exists... which is pointless. Its essentially a Modem, using a SIM card, the basic functions are Voice then VoiceDATA(CDM) then 1G (GPRS) at the very basic.

Comment: I have antenova check this website (the one under ARDUINO GSM SHIELD) http://www.antenova-m2m.com/products/partner-products/ http://www.ce-partner.pl/Plyta-GSM-GPRS-Shield-Arduino-65191%2828,125281,123985%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the shield.](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoGSMShield)

And this shows where the connections need to be made.

[image]

[image]

The Pi cannot record Audio without an extra USB card. The problem is, the Pi wont be able to do any kind of audio for you here. It might just be a really overpowered board to run this GSM.

One option is tho install RasPBX (Asterisk server) for VoiP. That will make sense. You can then connect all phones in your house (Using a SIP Client) to the Pi. You can call each other when in the same network, or if the GSM shield gets a call then all SIP clients will ring, audio recording. But you need to be able to record audio on the Pi. USB Sound card.

The other options are to use the Shield as a way to send and receive data in remote locations, where only GPRS is available. Sometimes when its really bad you can still use SMS messages to send and receive data.

Comment: Great! Thanks for ur detailed answer. Would you please clarify how to attach the speaker ? I could only see how do you attach the mic

Comment: What kind of speaker ? This board only supplies line audio. Meaning not amplified. So you connect an amplified speaker input to s1n s1p where n is negative and p is positive.

Comment: Thanks for ur time! I will give it a shoot this weekend. This should be a correct answer, logically.